# Excel : Data Validation, how to force the user to enter a string that is 2 char long?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to add some data validation on a cell in the latest Excel. I would like to force the user to enter a string that is two-char long, with the first char a digit, and the second char a letter.

e.g.

```
1m
2m
9w
8y
```

How would you do that?

Also, if a lower case letter is entered, i'd like to render it an upper case letter when the input is finished.

Comment: For part (2) it will have to be VBA. ie you can use a formula to test your condition as part (1), but the conversion will be code based

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only for the first part (no VBA needed), you can use Data Validation:

- Select the cell you want to check (`A1` for instance)
- In the Ribbon, go to **Data > Data Validation**
- In the `Allow:`, choose **Custom**
- In the field, put this formula: `=IF(AND(LEN(A1)=2,ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1,1))),ISTEXT(RIGHT(A1,1))),TRUE,FALSE)`
- In the tab **Error Alert**, change the dialog to explain to the user what he should do, something like:

> You have to enter a number followed by a letter.

Btw, you could add a check with an `UPPERCASE` test.

[EDIT] Also have a look at brettj's answer for a similar but optimized solution

Comment: there's a `text length` option for Data Validation

Comment: I have made a suggested change below for the text check portionn. I think you meant `ISNUMBER` rather than `ISNUM`. Plus you can shorten your solution to `AND(LEN(A1)=2,ISNUM(VALUE(LEFT(A1,1))),ISTEXT(RIGHT(A1,1)))` for the same impact, as this will return TRUE or FALse. cheers Dave

Comment: @brettdj: thanks. It's a pity my Excel is not in english, I have to translate every formula I create :(. I also edited my post so that people will also have a look at your answer even if mine is still the first one

Comment: That is really impressive. Your native language (and Excel version) are French? I had assumed you were an English speaker living in France.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate :). Actually, I am French and this is my native language (and Excel is in french too)

Answer (score 2):

Jerome,

In case you want to resolve this **without** VBA, you could

- use a (hidden) sheet where you enter all 260 combinations 0A through 9Z in one column.
- Give this range a name e.g. "MyList".
- go to your input sheet (e.g. A1) and use data validation, selecting the "list" option.
- In the source field, click [F3] to select "MyList".

If you need this data in uppercase, you can use the formula `=UPPER(A1)` where ever you use the input.

Answer (score 2):

Select range, then in the Data menu, choose Validation.
Allow: choose `Text length`, Minimum = 2, maximum = 2

Comment: Nice tip. It solves only part of the problem but relevant enough to be noted :)

Answer (score 2):

For the first part you will need a formula such as this for Data Validation

`=AND(LEN(A1)=2,ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1,1))),CODE(RIGHT(LOWER(A1),1))>=97,CODE(RIGHT(LOWER(A1),1))<=122)`

This part runs a case insensitive test for a letter between a to z `CODE(RIGHT(LOWER(A1),1))>=97,CODE(RIGHT(LOWER(A1),1))<=122)`

`ISTEXT(RIGHT(A1,1)))` will validate characters other than a-z to being text as it is a string test, even numbers will be allowed. This is why the `VALUE` portion of `(VALUE(LEFT(A1,1)))` is needed to force a numeric evaluation of the first position in the string

Comment: Since I liked the suggested approach, I tried this my self and ran into an issue. I "modified" the formula to: AND(LEN(A1)=2,ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1,1))),CODE(RIGHT(A1,1))>=65,CODE(RIGHT(A1,1))<=90) so that only capital letters are accepted. However, if I enter the formula directly in data validation it does not work. However, if I place the formula in an other cell and then refer to that cell inside data validation, it works.... Any idea why the direct formula doesn't work and the indirect reference does work?

Comment: OK, Finally got it to work inside data validation with the following formula: =IF(AND(LEN(A1)=2,ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1,1))),CODE(RIGHT(A1,1))>64,CODE(RIGHT(A1,1))<91),TRUE,FALSE)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an overkill method, literally just for fun (don't downvote me for having a little fun with VBA - this is actually useful to know how to do). It adds a data validation list to a range that only allows a number followed by an uppercase letter. I do this by quite literally adding every single combination allowable :) Of course you don't have to SELECT form the list, but if you try to type something that's not allowed, you get the buzzer :)

```
Sub AddValidation()

Dim cell As Range
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Dim alphabet As String, numbers As String
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
numbers = "1234567890"
Dim validList As String

For i = 1 To Len(numbers)
    For j = 1 To Len(alphabet)
        dict.Add Mid$(numbers, i, 1) & Mid$(alphabet, j, 1), 1
    Next
Next

validList = Join(dict.keys, ", ")

'Example using B1:B10
With Range("B1:B10").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
    AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=validList
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = "Invalid data entered"
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: did you really have to use a dict to put a comma between each letter and numbers? (especially if you have a loop to add the keys...) :D

Comment: You're absolutely right - at least at the start of my answer I seemed to somehow know I was doing things very unconventionally :0

Answer (score 0):

If you can use VBA then try to catch event Worksheet_Change:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "You just changed " & Target.Address
    ' your logic goes here
End Sub
```