# How to Disable specific keys in each cell in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have one excel sheet where user will enter meta data in each cell. What I need to do is write a macro which will allow only alpha numeric characters and comma.

I wrote a macro for test purpose which wouldn't allow special characters. But after I entered one valid character in cell it's allowing my disallowed characters. I don't know how to rectify it.

My code:

```
Private Sub WorkBook_Open()
       MsgBox "Running the Disable_Keys() Macro"
       Call ThisWorkbook.Disable_Keys
End Sub

Sub MyMsg()
    MsgBox "Press Another Key"
End Sub

Sub Disable_Keys()

     Dim I As Long
     Dim KeysArray As Variant
     Dim Key As Variant

     KeysArray = Array("@", "!", "~", "#", "$", "&", "|", "\", ":", "*", "_", "-", "=", "'", ";", "<", ">", "?", "/", "'", ":")

     For Each Key In KeysArray
          Application.OnKey Key, "ThisWorkbook.MyMSg"
     Next Key
  End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you just use data validation? For example you could adapt my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8512679/641067

Comment: I don't know much about data validation can you specify what to do to allow only alpha numeric character and comma for certain cells.

Comment: use the accepted answer of the question, brettdj posted. In the excel-dialog of data valitdation you can use "custom/user defined" criteria and specify a formula or even better in your specific case: use "List" ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will check for if there is something that is *not* 0-9,a-z or a comma
If you want to exclude specific characters, then the `.Pattern` would be what you change
If it finds something, then the cell is invalid, and it will clear the cell.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim TestCell
Dim RE As Object
Dim REMatches As Object

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .MultiLine = False
    .Global = False
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "[^0-9A-Z,]"
End With

For Each TestCell In Target.Cells
    Set REMatches = RE.Execute(TestCell.Value)
    If REMatches.Count > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid:" & TestCell.Address & "-" & TestCell.Value
        TestCell.Value = ""
    End If
Next

End Sub
```